# To enable or disable the input field based on the value of select component in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am having 2 component **select** and **input** component.as shown in below image.

[image]

**Scenario:** Here by default i have set **input** field as **disabled**.If i choose some option from **select** component then the field becomes active.This scenario is working fine.

**Expected Result:**
I should have another option in the **select** component(i,e dropdown) to disable the input field again(If user doesn't want want choose anything from select component).

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/enabling-the-input-in-selecting-the-dropdwon-dzmfdx?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.html) link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do some editings. in your Html file

```
<mat-form-field class="id-name">
        <mat-select placeholder="ID Card" formControlName="IDproof" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let IDproof of  IDproofs" [value]="IDproof.value">
                {{IDproof.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
        <mat-option  [value]="'disabled'">
                {{'disabled'}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

And in your ts file

```
onChange(data) {
    if(data && data != 'disabled'){
      this.myForm.get('idNum').enable()
    }else{
      this.myForm.get('idNum').disable()
    }
  }
```

Comment: wished we had a one liner code that could be done on the html itself. .....

Answer (score 4):

Another option is make a directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[enableControl]'
})
export class EnableControlDirective {
    @Input() set enableControl(condition: boolean) {
        if (this.ngControl) {
            if (this.ngControl.control) {
                if (condition)
                    this.ngControl.control.enable();
                else
                    this.ngControl.control.disable();
            }
        }
  }
  constructor(private ngControl : NgControl ) {}
```

So you can use the directive like

```
  <input [enableControl]="condition">
  //e.g.
  <input [enableControl]="myForm.get('IDproof').value">
```

and we don't worry about changes, disables variables, etc