# How to prevent to selecting the dropdown value in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one dropdown and radio button [Yes, No], which works fine. But I have to add one condition while changing the dropdown value.

1. If the radio button selected value is Yes, then we can use dropdown as usual.
2. But if radio button selected value is No then we can not change the selected value of dropdown. Whatever value is selected in the dropdown, just keep it. if a user tries to change the dropdown value then a popup message will come and say. You can not change the value if the radio button is No.

We don't want to make the dropdown disable.

I have tried multiple codes but getting one issue. On change, I can show the message but the selected value is being changed. I don't want to set the same value again because, onset value, multiple events are firing.

So, basically on change of dropdown. I want to check the condition and show the message and keep the dropdown selected as an initial value.
Here is the sample code.

```
    this.controls.dropdowneControl.valueChanges.pipe(pairwise()).subscribe(([preData, data]: [any, any]) => {
          debugger;
          if (data !== undefined && data != null) {
            currentValue = data;
            previousValue = preData;


              if (previousValue == 'A' && currentValue == 'B' && radioButtonValue == 'No') {
                this.alert(‘Some message.');

//Don’t change the dropdown value                
                return false;
              }
}});
```

Please suggest something.

Thanks

Comment: give ur samples..?

Comment: @Edison Added Sample code in question.

Comment: Cant you just not change data model instead?

Comment: @Antoniossss Did not get you, could you please explain it bit clear?

Comment: on dropdown change call a function which will check the current value of radio button,if radio button is No set the model value of dropdown to the desired selected value else change to value to newly selected value

Comment: @DeepakVerma Thanks, but as I have mentioned that I don't want to set the value, only prevent to change the value of dropdown.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619826/to-enable-or-disable-the-input-field-based-on-the-value-of-select-component-in-a?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the change event in the controls. For radio controls, you might use something like `(change)="handleYesNo($event)"`. On selecting `No`, set the target (select/dropdown) value back to earlier value which is in a var which you can save when radio is set to `Yes`. Here the select/dropdown is not disabled at all. A message is shown when user tries to change selected value from dropdown while radio is set to `No`.

```
handleSelect(evt) {
var target = evt.target;

if (this.yesOrNo == true)
{
  this.previousValue = target.value;
}
else{
  target.value = this.previousValue;
  alert("You can't change the value if the Yes/No Radio selection is No.")
}
}
```

Your component model:

```
yesOrNo: boolean;
selectedValue: string;
previousValue: string;
```

Complete component: (simplest one)

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple-form',
  templateUrl: './simple-form.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class SimpleFormComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  yesOrNo: boolean;
  selectedValue: string;
  previousValue: string;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: [null, Validators.required],
      sayYesOrNo: [null, Validators.required],
    });
  }

  handleYesNo(evt) {
    if (this.yesOrNo == true)
    {
      console.log("Yes");
    }
    else{
      console.log("No");
    }
  }

  handleSelect(evt) {
    var target = evt.target;

    if (this.yesOrNo == true)
    {
      this.previousValue = target.value;
    }
    else{
      target.value = this.previousValue;
      alert("You can't change the value if the Yes/No Radio selection is No.")
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="form">

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">      

      <input [(ngModel)]="yesOrNo" type="radio" (change)="handleYesNo($event)" formControlName="sayYesOrNo" name="sayYesOrNo" value="1"> Yes<br>
      <input [(ngModel)]="yesOrNo" type="radio" (change)="handleYesNo($event)" formControlName="sayYesOrNo" name="sayYesOrNo" value="0"> No<br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">      
      <label for="dropDown" class="control-label">Select:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="dropDown" (change)="handleSelect($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" formControlName="dropDown" name="dropDown">
        <option value="opt1" >Option 1</option>
        <option value="opt2" >Option 2</option>
      </select>

    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!form.valid">
    Submit
  </button>

</form>
```

Hope it helps. I have kept it simple here just to demo the point.