# Disable input on matDatePicker [Angular Material]

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hey i have input date picker from angular material and i try to make the value disable and let the user choose only from the date picker Calendar and it doesn't work for me.

This is my input:

```
<p class="p-rtl">
    <mat-form-field class="input-min" appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Finish Date</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [formControl]="date">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</p>
```

The problem is that the user can insert bad inputs and i want to block the user for this inputs.

I  try to google it and read reference and nothing not work for me.

[image]

Comment: Just add "disabled" property to the input, `<input disabled matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [formControl]="date">`

Comment: Its disable me the date picker calendar but the input its same  available

Comment: @TheUnreal, a FormControl can be disabled, when is created, or using "disabled()" method or using a directive https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619826/to-enable-or-disable-the-input-field-based-on-the-value-of-select-component-in-a/52622123#52622123

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to disable your input with `disabled` in HTML component you have a warning in console (reactive form).

To be able to avoid this, you can disable a `FormControl` with

```js
 date: new FormControl({value: null, disabled: true})
```

Then to be sure that the user can't write anything you can put `readonly` attribute in the template

```html
<p class="p-rtl">
    <mat-form-field class="input-min" appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Finish Date</mat-label>
        <input matInput readonly [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [formControl]="date">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling the entire form you can disable like below

```html
<p class="p-rtl">
    <mat-form-field class="input-min" appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Finish Date</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [formControl]="date" disabled>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker  disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</p>
```

Comment: I am not at all sure that disabled="false" will work