# Disable ONLY FormControl in a nested form

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I have a nested group and basically I want to disable just the FormControl ones. I know I can use something like `this.form.control.get("formControlName").disable()`, but I want to avoid it since I am going to implement this login into a bigger projects, where the formControlName is retrieved dynamically.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-zk9pqm?file=app/app.component.html)

How do I disable only the formControl (in this case the form fields) without disabling / enabling the other formGroup?

Comment: What is your question? If you just to avoid the hardcoded string, pass it as argument

Comment: Sorry! I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

just in .html

```
(change)="childToggle($event.checked,'child')"
```

and

```
childToggle(checked,controlName)
{
  checked?this.form.get(controlName).disable():this.form.get(controlName).enable()
}
```

Anyway, you can create a directive like [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619826/to-enable-or-disable-the-input-field-based-on-the-value-of-select-component-in-a/52622123#52622123)