# Making input disable reactive in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I'm having a hard time putting an additional disable condition on an input in Angular. Imagine a basic control:

```html
<input [formControl]="control">
```

I know that to disable or enable this input, it's normally a simple call to `enable()` or `disable()`.

I'm working on a really large codebase. In many places `control.disable()` is called on the control or parent controls to force the disabling of the input.

I'd like for the input to be temporarily disabled while an API (possibly multiple) is loading in the background, i.e:

```html
<input [formControl]="control" [disabled]="control.disabled || apiLoading()" >
```

However Angular gives me a warning, because it doesn't want me to bind to `disabled` and instead wants me to call `control.disable()`. This is *really* awkward for me:

1. I'd have to call `control.disable()/enable()` every time the value of `apiLoading()` changes, this is possible [via a directive as this blog suggests](https://netbasal.com/disabling-form-controls-when-working-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-549dd7b42110).
2. But like I said, I'm dealing with a massive codebase. `control.disable()` is already called all over the place, at unpredictable times, and it takes priority. Whenever `apiLoading()` is false, I'd have set the control back to its last set disable state that *wasnt* set by `apiLoading()`.

#2 has been a really hard to implement for me. I have to keep the last set state, which I tried via a combination of `control.statusChange` and `emitEvent: false`, but ultimately hit conflicts when `statusChange` events got emitted when the control value changed. I started to go down a rabbit hole.

I just need something simple: temporary disabling while APIs are loading to apply *on top of* disabling done elsewhere in the codebase, but because I'm forced to direct my disabling via `enable()/disable()`, I have to be extra careful not to undo `disable()`s already called elsewhere in the huge codebase I'm working on.

What is the simplest way to achieve something like the following without having to drop the use of `formControl` (which does touched/dirty detection nicely)?

```html
<input [formControl]="control" [disabled]="control.disabled || apiLoading()" >
```

Comment: or use [attr.disabled] -this only disabled the input, not disable the formControl-  or use a directive, see. e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619826/to-enable-or-disable-the-input-field-based-on-the-value-of-select-component-in-a/52622123#52622123)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way I'm not entirely happy with but does work. With a custom directive, I can no-op the `setDisabledState` on the value accessor, but hold on to the original in a variable. That way I can disable the input based on my custom condition - not by having to call `disable()/enable()` - and the `formControlDirective` has no control on the disabling.

```js
import { FormControlDirective } from "@angular/forms";
import { Directive, Input } from "@angular/core";

/**
 * This directive helps to provide a custom method for disabling a form control
 * when using the FormControl directive, rather than managing the disabling of
 * the control via the enable/disable methods - which can be quite impractical.
 */
@Directive({
    // eslint-disable-next-line @angular-eslint/directive-selector
    selector: "[customDisable]",
})
export class CustomDisableDirective {

    disabler: (boolean) => void;

    @Input() set customDisable(condition: boolean) {
        this.disabler(condition);
    }

    constructor(private dir: FormControlDirective) {
        // No-ops the accessor disable so that the formControl directive has
        // no effect over the disabling, and disabling is controlled here.
        const accessor = this.dir.valueAccessor;
        this.disabler = accessor.setDisabledState.bind(accessor);
        this.dir.valueAccessor.setDisabledState = () => {};
    }
}
```

Then in the html:

```html
<input [formControl]="control" [customDisable]="control.disabled || apiLoading()" >
```

Answer (score -1):

apiLoading() Loading should return an Observable then use async pipe to consume it:

```
<input [formControl]="control" [disabled]="control.disabled || apiLoading()|async" >
```