# Dynamically Change colour/css styling of Disabled text boxes based on boolean value

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

```
<label [invalid]="false" invalidText="" placeholder="Placeholder text">
    Middle names (optional)
    <input ibmText [attr.disabled]="isApplicationLocked" [invalid]="false" placeholder=""
    (keyup)="applicantControlValueChanged()" formControlName="PersonMiddleName">
<label>
```

In my angular project (using typescript). I have a Boolean called "isApplicationLocked". When this boolean is true, it will disable the text box and not allow the user to edit the text. However, not all portions of the textbox are greyed out. The border and label still remain as black. How am I able to dynamically change the colour of all attributes in the text box, based on this value?

I am also using scss

Answer (score 2):

First, you add the `isApplicationLocked` variable into the form group.

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  PersonMiddleName: new FormControl(
    ...
  ),
  disabled: this.isApplicationLocked
});
```

And then, you need to create a subscription for changing of this value.

```
this.formGroup.get("disabled").valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  this.changeDisabledState(value);
});
```

Here `changeDisabledState` function is to change the disabled state of the input control.

```
changeDisabledState(value: boolean): void {
    if(value){
        this.checkoutForm.controls['PersonMiddleName'].enable();
    }else{
        this.checkoutForm.controls['PersonMiddleName'].disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like more use a disable pipe, see e.g. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619826/to-enable-or-disable-the-input-field-based-on-the-value-of-select-component-in-a/52622123#52622123). In this way you don't add a new FormControl to the FormGroup

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:read-only` CSS pseudo-class, to change the style for readonly mode on input or textarea.

```css
    input:read-only,
    textarea:read-only {
      background-color: #black;

    }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-only