# How to disable an input FormControl in a Reactive Form with a condition in Angular 15?

Tags: angular, form-control, formgroups, angular15

I have a form where I can input a student Id. Below that are two input boxes,
full name and email. When I load the page, only the student Id input box should be enabled and the two inputs below it are disabled. When I enter the student Id and if it has a record, that's the only time that the input boxes for the full name and email are enabled.

When I used Angular 13, it was able to work with this for each input

```
[attr.disable]="!isStudentIdReal"
```

However, I recently updated to Angular 15 and this stopped working. I was able to find a solution where:

```
studentName : [{value: '', disable: true}],
email : [{value: '', disable: true}]
```

This disabled the input boxes however, it won't enable them because I don't have a condition.

Comment: Furthermore the Mathieu Rieger's answer, you can use a directive. See, e.g.[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619826/to-enable-or-disable-the-input-field-based-on-the-value-of-select-component-in-a/52622123#52622123)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [breaking change](https://angular.io/guide/update-to-version-15#setdisabledstate-is-always-called-when-a-controlvalueaccessor-is-attached) about that in angular 15.

You will need to import the `ReactiveFormsModule` with a config to restore the previous behavior:

```
ReactiveFormsModule.withConfig({callSetDisabledState: 'whenDisabledForLegacyCode'})
```

The other possibility being calling `enable()` on the FormControl when the value of `isStudentIdReal` changes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still fairly new to Angular. Where do I put ReactiveFormsModule.withConfig({callSetDisabledState: 'whenDisabledForLegacyCode'}) or how do I use it?

Comment: You replace `ReactiveFormsModule` where it's currently imported. Most likely your AppModule !

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/uftUxKo is this where it's supposed to be?

Comment: This is the only answer as the OP asked specifically about Angular 15 update. I have a different way to disable my formControl and this also helped. Good answer!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

use [disabled]="!isStudentIdReal"

Comment: I also tried this and it still didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: This is may lead to complex behaviours. The disabled input here refers to the HTMLInputElement disabled property, not the `FormControl` disabled. A consequence of using this is that the control may be enabled but the input disabled (hence if the user unlocks the `input` via devTools, it will pass the information to the `formControl`. Use this when using `FormsModule` aka the Template-driven approach and not with the `ReactiveFormsModule` aka the Reactive approach.

Answer (score -1):

Using the `ReactiveForms` approach in Angular, every `FormControl` has a set of properties and methods. The ones you are looking for would be `disable()` and `enable()`.

You can call them directly in the component, not the template, through the `FormGroup` that contains your controls.

Let's say your `FormGroup` is called `studentInfo`. You could add to your component some getters to access directly those controls:

```js
get studentName() {
  return this.studentInfo.get('studentName');
}

get studentEmail() {
  return this.studentInfo.get('email');
}
```

Then, inside the method that checks the student ID you could write something like this:

```js
  // code that checks student id
  if (!isStudentIdReal) {
    this.studentName.disable();
    this.studentEmail.disable();
  } else {
    this.studentName.enable();
    this.studentEmail.enable();
  }
  // rest of the code
```

This code can be written more elegantly, but I hope it helps you get the gist.

Answer (score -1):

In your input tag in html:

```
[disabled]="!isStudentIdReal"
```

In your ts file:

```
enableOrDisable(){
  if(this.formgroupname.controls['id'].value){
    this.isStudentIdReal=true
  }else{
    this.isStudentIdReal=false
  }
}
```

call the above method in change of id input tag as well as in `constructor` or `ngOnInIt`.

Comment: Thanks @bvdb to edit the answer, unfortunately the answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Eliseo indeed it is. :-) but at least now we can read it. The answer of Matthieu Riegler is pretty good though.