# I want to enable inputs of a reactive form according to the radio inputs

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I am making a form that automatically lists the products that are in a database and each product has a number type input, 4 radio type inputs, 1 checkbox type input and one text type input on the page, which I want is that when the inputs of type radio are "roto" or "regalado", the input checkbox and text are enabled, but I am not getting it, what I tried is this, I attach my component class and my template:

(The database is being simulated by `this.simulation`)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'principal',
  templateUrl: './principal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./principal.component.css']
})
export class PrincipalComponent implements OnInit {

  public formulario: FormGroup;

  public simulacion: any;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.formulario = this.fb.group({
      productos: this.fb.array([
        // Groups with their own drivers that correspond to each product in the database
      ])
    });

    this.simulacion = [  // THIS SIMULATES THE PRODUCTS COLLECTION FROM THE DATABASE
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906d951c2ef7ee441afe67"
        },
        producto: "1kg",
        precio: 2000,
        precioPromo: 1500,
        fecha: "19-6-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906e0b1c2ef7ee441afe68"
        },
        producto: "1/2kg",
        precio: 1300,
        fecha: "10-4-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906e2d1c2ef7ee441afe69"
        },
        producto: "1/4kg",
        precio: 700,
        fecha: "02-3-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906d951c2ef7ee441afe67"
        },
        producto: "14kg",
        precio: 2000,
        precioPromo: 1500,
        fecha: "19-6-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906d951c2ef7ee441afe67"
        },
        producto: "4r4",
        precio: 2000,
        precioPromo: 1500,
        fecha: "19-6-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906d951c2ef7ee441afe67"
        },
        producto: "as",
        precio: 2000,
        precioPromo: 1500,
        fecha: "19-6-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906e0b1c2ef7ee441afe68"
        },
        producto: "1/gd",
        precio: 1300,
        fecha: "10-4-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906e2d1c2ef7ee441afe69"
        },
        producto: "1/adv",
        precio: 700,
        fecha: "02-3-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906d951c2ef7ee441afe67"
        },
        producto: "25h",
        precio: 2000,
        precioPromo: 1500,
        fecha: "19-6-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906d951c2ef7ee441afe67"
        },
        producto: "oñ",
        precio: 2000,
        precioPromo: 1500,
        fecha: "19-6-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906e0b1c2ef7ee441afe68"
        },
        producto: "1/mmb",
        precio: 1300,
        fecha: "10-4-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906e2d1c2ef7ee441afe69"
        },
        producto: "14asdf",
        precio: 700,
        fecha: "02-3-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906d951c2ef7ee441afe67"
        },
        producto: "asffdw",
        precio: 2000,
        precioPromo: 1500,
        fecha: "19-6-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906d951c2ef7ee441afe67"
        },
        producto: "asdfas",
        precio: 2000,
        precioPromo: 1500,
        fecha: "19-6-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906e0b1c2ef7ee441afe68"
        },
        producto: "ASHEE",
        precio: 1300,
        fecha: "10-4-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906d951c2ef7ee441afe67"
        },
        producto: "asdfdw",
        precio: 2000,
        precioPromo: 1500,
        fecha: "19-6-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906d951c2ef7ee441afe67"
        },
        producto: "a3dfas",
        precio: 2000,
        precioPromo: 1500,
        fecha: "19-6-23"
      },
      {
        _id: {
          $oid: "64906e0b1c2ef7ee441afe68"
        },
        producto: "dHEE",
        precio: 1300,
        fecha: "10-4-23"
      },
    ]

  }

  enlistarProductos() {
    for (let produ in this.simulacion) {                              

      this.productos().push(
        this.fb.group({
          actual: this.fb.control('1', [Validators.required]),
          condicion: this.fb.control('efectivo', [Validators.required]),
          noVendido: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required]),
          desc: this.fb.control({ value: '', disabled: true }, [Validators.required])
        })
      )

    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.enlistarProductos()

  }

  productos() {
    return this.formulario.get("productos") as FormArray;
  }

}
```

and this is the template:

```html
<div id="body">

    <div id="container" [formGroup]="formulario">

        <!-- **************************************** -->
        <form id="contenedorgeneral" formArrayName="productos">

            <ng-container *ngFor="let input of productos().controls ; let i=index;" [formGroupName]="i">

                <div class="cajita">

                    <div class="title">
                        <h2>{{this.simulacion[i].producto}}</h2><span>15</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sectoragregado">
                        <div class="content">

                            <input type="button" value="-">
                            <input type="number" formControlName="actual" placeholder="Escriba...">
                            <input type="submit" value="+" [disabled]="productos().controls[i].invalid">

                        </div>
                        <div class="pago"> <!-- es igual a formulario -->
                            <div class="selectpago"> <!-- es igual a checkbox -->
                                <input id="{{this.simulacion[i].producto}}efectivo" value="efectivo" type="radio"
                                    formControlName="condicion">
                                <label for="{{this.simulacion[i].producto}}efectivo">Efectivo</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="selectpago">
                                <input id="{{this.simulacion[i].producto}}debito" value="debito" type="radio"
                                    formControlName="condicion">
                                <label for="{{this.simulacion[i].producto}}debito">Debito</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rotoregalado">

                        <div class="rotoregaladodata"> <!-- es igual a formulario -->
                            <div class="selectrotoregalado"> <!-- es igual a checkbox -->
                                <input id="{{this.simulacion[i].producto}}roto" value="roto" type="radio"
                                    formControlName="condicion">
                                <label for="{{this.simulacion[i].producto}}roto">Roto</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="selectrotoregalado">
                                <input id="{{this.simulacion[i].producto}}regalado" value="regalado" type="radio"
                                    formControlName="condicion">
                                <label for="{{this.simulacion[i].producto}}regalado">Regalado</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="selectnovendido">
                            <div class="selectbox">
                                <input id="{{this.simulacion[i].producto}}noVendido" type="checkbox"
                                    formControlName="noVendido">
                                <label for="{{this.simulacion[i].producto}}noVendido">No vendido</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="selectcantidad">
                                <input type="text" formControlName="desc" placeholder="Escriba...">
                                <!-- [disabled]="this.productos().controls[i].value.condicion == 'efectivo' || this.productos().controls[i].value.condicion == 'debito'" -->
                                <!-- [disabled]="getCondicion(i)" -->
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </ng-container>

        </form>
        <!-- **************************************** -->

        <div id="cerrado"><input type="button" value="Cerrar Caja"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="container2">
        <div id="historial">
            <div id="historial1">
                <h2 class="titulo">Historial de VENTAS</h2>
                <div id="indicator">
                    <p>Producto</p>
                    <p>Cantidad</p>
                    <p>Precio</p>
                    <p>Turno</p>
                </div>
                <div id="span">
                    <div class="span2">
                        <span>1kg</span><span>3</span><span>$2000</span><span>Lautaro M</span>
                        <div class="closebutton">
                            <input type="button" value="X">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span2">
                        <span>1kg</span><span>3</span><span>$2000</span><span>Lautaro M</span>
                        <div class="closebutton">
                            <input type="button" value="X">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="historial2">
                <h2 class="titulo">Historial de REGISTROS</h2>
                <div id="span">
                    <div class="span2">
                        <span>Fecha: 12/30 Hora: 16:05</span><span> TERMICO KILO LISO </span><span>+200</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span2">
                        <span>Fecha: 12/30 Hora: 16:05</span><span> TERMICO KILO LISO </span><span>+200</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="retiroygasto">
            <div id="retiros">
                <h2 class="titulo">Retiros</h2>
                <div id="retiros2">
                    <div class="retiro">
                        <span>Fecha/hora</span><span>Turno</span><input type="text" placeholder="Cantidad..."><input
                            type="button" value="Ok">
                    </div>
                    <div class="retiro">
                        <span>16/5 - 17:00</span><span>Lautaro M</span><span>2000</span><input type="button" value="X">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="gastos">
                <h2 class="titulo">Gastos</h2>
                <div id="gastos2">
                    <div class="gasto">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Gastos"><input type="text" placeholder="Detalles"><input
                            type="button" value="Ok">
                    </div>
                    <div class="gasto">
                        <span>2000</span><span>Papel higienico</span><input type="button" value="X">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To enable/disable a FormControl (and the input associated to it) you should use enable() and disable() method. Really the best bet is use a directive, see, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619826/to-enable-or-disable-the-input-field-based-on-the-value-of-select-component-in-a/52622123#52622123)