# Angular disable form control based on other control default value upon form initialization?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control, formgroups

I have a simple radio button in Angular app with a default value. OnChange of the value for the radio button value, I am disabling a input. This works fine. But, when the form is initialized with a default radio button value, the input is not disabled. How can I make the input disabled upon form initialization?

```js
export class AppComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({
    gender: new FormControl('female', Validators.required),
    weight: new FormControl(22),
  });

  get f() {
    return this.form.controls;
  }

  submit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }

  changeGender(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    if (e.target.value === 'female') {
      this.form.controls.weight.disable();
    } else {
      this.form.get('weight').enable();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
      <div>
        <input
          id="male"
          type="radio"
          value="male"
          name="gender"
          formControlName="gender"
          (change)="changeGender($event)"
        />
        <label for="male">Male</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input
          id="female"
          type="radio"
          value="female"
          name="gender"
          formControlName="gender"
          (change)="changeGender($event)"
        />
        <label for="female">Female</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" formControlName="weight" placeholder="weight" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I want to disable the weight input when form is initialized.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-buttons-reactive-forms-tienanhvn-nu9kef?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: You can use  disabled="true" in your input box. You are anyway enabling it on changeGender()

Comment: @Jarvis, you can not use `disabled` in your input when we works with Reactive Forms because this not disable the form control, so Angular give you an error. If only want to disable the html control you need use `[attr.disabled]="condition?true:null"`. Be careful this **only disabled the html input**, don't take account the formControl that it's enable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable form with disable state you could pass `disabled` on FormControl like this.

```
form = new FormGroup({
    gender: new FormControl('female', Validators.required),
    weight: new FormControl({ value:22, disabled: true }),
  });
```

**OR**

In Reactive Forms, the valueChanges property provides an Observable that you can subscribe to in order to receive updates when the form value changes.
To get the current form value you could pipe `startsWith` operator like this.

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.form.valueChanges
      .pipe(startWith(this.form.value))
      .subscribe((value) => {
        if (value.gender === 'female') {
          this.f.weight.disable({ emitEvent: false });
        } else {
          this.f.weight.enable({ emitEvent: false });
        }
      });
  }
```

**[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-buttons-reactive-forms-tienanhvn-ajucai?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

To makes more "transparent", I like use a directive to disable, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619826/to-enable-or-disable-the-input-field-based-on-the-value-of-select-component-in-a/52622123#52622123)

Based in the directive in the before link, we can use ngAfterViewInit and change a bit

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[disableControl]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class DisableControlDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  condition!: boolean;
  @Input('disableControl') set _(value: boolean) {
    this.condition = value;
    this.checkControl();
  }
  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}
  checkControl() {
    if (this.ngControl && this.ngControl.control)
      this.ngControl.control[this.condition ? 'disable' : 'enable']();
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.checkControl();
  }
}
```

You use

```
<input type="text" formControlName="weight" placeholder="weight" 
       [disableControl]="form.value.gender=='female'" 
/>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-yvfqhs?file=src%2Fdisable-control.directive.ts)