# Input lag in Angular Reactive forms

Tags: angular

I struggle to find a clean solution for a simple FormGroup with conditions to display 3 fields.

Let's take 3 input number A,B and C which are defined in my a FormGroup. B is enabled if A===0 and C is enabled if B===0.

Here are my 3 inputs :

```
<p-inputNumber 
class="form-control w-200"
name="fieldA"
formControlName="fieldA"
(focusout)="activateFields()" >
</p-inputNumber>

<p-inputNumber 
class="form-control w-200"
name="fieldB"
formControlName="fieldB"
(focusout)="activateFields()" >
</p-inputNumber>

<p-inputNumber 
class="form-control w-200"
name="fieldB"
formControlName="fieldB"
(focusout)="activateFields()" >
</p-inputNumber>
```

The method *activateFields()* enable or disable fields.

When i was debugging, i have noticed that there is a difference between what i am typing and what my method is checking.

For example when i type : "0", my method activateFields() check the FormGroup and fieldA value is null.
If i add "1" , my field value is "01" but in the formGroup the value is "0"
if i delete the 1 i previously added, activateFields() will check "01".

This phenomen happens sometimes, and create issues in my page.

The only way i have found to get the "real time" value is to change my input like that :

```
<input class="form-control"
 type="number" formControlName="fieldA" name="fieldA" (input)="onInputChange($event,'A')"/>

<input class="form-control"
 type="number" formControlName="fieldB" name="fieldB" (input)="onInputChange($event,'B')"/>

<input class="form-control"
 type="number" formControlName="fieldC" name="fieldC" (input)="onInputChange($event,'C')"/>
```

And in my *onInputChange($event)* method i manually update the form value of each field :

```
onInputChange(event: any, arg: any) {
    inputValue = Number(event.target.value);
    if (arg === 'A') {
      this.editForm.get(['fieldA'])!.setValue(inputValue);
    } else if (arg === 'B') {
      this.editForm.get(['fieldB'])!.setValue(inputValue);
    } else if (arg === 'C') {
      this.editForm.get(['fieldC'])!.setValue(inputValue);
    
    // my method to enable/disabled fields
    this.activateFields();
  }
```

I think my solution is dirty, but i don't know how to solve this issue ?

Comment: The `focusout` event triggers before Angular has a chance to update the FormGroup. Instead of an event you can use the `valueChanges` observable of the FormGroup to react to changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
onInputChange(event: any, arg: any) {
  inputValue = Number(event.target.value);
  if (arg === 'A') {
    this.editForm.get(['fieldA'])!.setValue(inputValue);
    if(inputValue === 0){
      this.editForm.get(['fieldB']).enable();
    }
    else{
      this.editForm.get(['fieldB']).disable();
    }
  } 
  else if (arg === 'B') {
    this.editForm.get(['fieldB'])!.setValue(inputValue);
    if(inputValue === 0){
    this.editForm.get(['fieldC']).enable();
    }
      else{
      this.editForm.get(['fieldC']).disable();
    }
  } 
  else if (arg === 'C') {
    this.editForm.get(['fieldC'])!.setValue(inputValue);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

p-inputnumber has a property "disabled". You can simply use

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <p-inputNumber inputId="integeronly"  
                   formControlName="control1"> 
    </p-inputNumber>
    <p-inputNumber inputId="integeronly" 
                   [disabled]="formGroup.get('control1')?.value==0" 
                   formControlName="control2"> 
    </p-inputNumber>
</form>
```

Well, this not "disable" the formControl, to disable a formControl I suggest use a directive like, e.g. [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76832358/angular-disable-form-control-based-on-other-control-default-value-upon-form-init/76833557#76833557)

See how, in this way we translate all the responsability to the .html